# Jquery event.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I put together a bit of Jquery to validate a form on my website.  Essentially, I'm using event.preventDefault(); to inhibit the form from submitting in the case of invalid input.

This code works perfectly in Google Chrome but does not work at all in Firefox (The form is sent to my server even when errors exist).  Am I doing something incorrectly or is there a more appropriate method of accomplishing this?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//validate application form
$('#applyForm').submit(function() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var appForm = $("#appForm").val();

        // validate appForm
        var extension = appForm.replace(/^.*\./, '');

        if (extension == appForm) {
            extension = '';
        } else {
            extension = extension.toLowerCase();
        }

        switch (extension) {
            case 'doc':
            case 'docx':
            case 'txt':
            case 'pdf':

            break;

            default:
                // Cancel the form submission
                $('#appFormLabel').css('color', '#B32017');
                event.preventDefault();
        }


        if(name.length <= 1 && email.length >= 6) {
            // name field is invalid (highlight name box & block submission)
            $('#name').css('border', '2px solid #B32017');
            $('#nameLabel').css('color', '#B32017');
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (email.length <= 5 && name.length >= 2) {
            // email field is invalid (highlight email box & block submission)
            $('#email').css('border', '2px solid #B32017');
            $('#emailLabel').css('color', '#B32017');
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (email.length <= 5 && name.length <= 1) {
            // both invalid, highlight and block
            $('#name, #email').css('border', '2px solid #B32017');
            $('#nameLabel, #emailLabel').css('color', '#B32017');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && $('#name').val() != '' && $('#email').val()) {
        $('#submitApply').trigger('click');
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is because you don't explicitly declare `event` anywhere. Try to receive the function like this:

```
$('#applyForm').submit(function(event) {

  // ... more stuff
  // event.preventDefault();

});
```

It probably works in Chrome because it perhaps catches this type of error for you, and Firefox isn't so lenient (a good thing in my mind).

Comment: That was it, thanks! Total oversight on my part...

Comment: Perfect! Glad we found it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `event` inside your `submit` function:

```
$('#applyForm').submit(function(event) {
```